# Error while installing Halyard

Tags: gnupg, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Im trying to install halyard in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have downloaded installhalyard script using curl
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinnaker/halyard/master/install/debian/InstallHalyard.sh

After Im executing sudo bash InstallHalyard.sh to install halyard command.
But Its not getting installed and showing the below error

```
jayanth@jayanth-VirtualBox:~$ sudo bash InstallHalyard.sh 
[sudo] password for jayanth: 
Please supply a non-root user to run Halyard as: jayanth
Halyard version will be stable 
Halyard will be downloaded from gs://spinnaker-artifacts/halyard 
Halyard config will come from bucket gs://halconfig 
Halconfig will be stored at /home/jayanth/.hal/config
Uninstall script is located at /home/jayanth/.hal/uninstall.sh
Running ubuntu 16.04
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmptyeoozb6/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmptyeoozb6/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 86F44E2A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
**Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.**
gpg: /tmp/tmptyeoozb6/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 86F44E2A: public key "Launchpad OpenJDK builds (all archs)" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Due to the above error, Im unable to install Halyard.
Please help me here.

BR
Jayanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have again tried `sudo apt-get update` this time and installed `open ssh client and server`.

This time it worked.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server`

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you either had a problem with network connectivity or some other reason that your system can't reach the host `keyserver.ubuntu.com.` Make sure you can reach that server (try pinging it for instance) and your install should work.

Comment: Tried pinging keyserver.ubuntu.com...
but still facing the same issue

jayanth@jayanth-VirtualBox:~$ ping keyserver.ubuntu.com
PING keyserver.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from boquila.canonical.com (91.189.89.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=143 ms
64 bytes from boquila.canonical.com (91.189.89.49): icmp_seq=10 ttl=51 time=144 ms
^C
--- keyserver.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9017ms

Comment: You could try installing the key yourself so the install script doesn't have to, that would move it along.

Comment: jayanth@jayanth-spinnaker:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371 --recv-keys 86F44E2A
Executing: /tmp/tmp.H67DLShNWT/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371
--recv-keys
86F44E2A
gpg: requesting key 86F44E2A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 86F44E2A: "Launchpad OpenJDK builds (all archs)" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1


I tried adding manually..  but still unable to resolve that issue

Comment: gpg --export --armor 86F44E2A | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update

I used this as well to install the key.. but still no use..

Comment: you mean the script still gets stuck at the same place?

Comment: the script exited after throwing the same error above mentioned..
No Change in the above Installhalyard script even after apt-key add.. :(

Comment: Yes..

I have again tried **sudo apt-get** update this time and installed open ssh client and server.

This time it got worked. :D

Thank for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

i use below command to deploy halyard

```
kubectl create deployment hal --image gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/halyard:1.20.2
```